# Draw equipotential lines on scatter plot in Python

Tags: python, plot

I have random data on x and y axis. I'd like to draw equipotential lines on which |xy|=constant over the scatter plot of (x,y). I need some help with this. Thank you!

Here is the example of what I want:
[image]

Comment: Well, just compute `|v| = constant/|u|` for a range of `u` values and plot those data pairs.

Comment: Thank you, this way works. I was constantly thinking of contour plots, because I want to have multiple plots with multiple constant values.

Answer (score 1):

As @fgnu says, you can simply plot one or more lines on the same axis that you plot your scatter points. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

u = np.random.random(500) * 2 - 1
v = np.random.random(500) * 200 - 100

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(u,v)

# now plot the hyperbola |xy| = 1 
x = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
y1 = 1/np.abs(x)
y2 = -y1
ax.plot(x,y1,'k-')
ax.plot(x,y2,'k-')
plt.show()
```

I don't know the range of your random points, so I can't guess what constant would be appropriate for your lines here.

[image]

EDIT To count the number of points "inside" the curve, you could use:

```
ninside = 0
for xi, yi in zip(u, v):
    if abs(yi) < 1/np.abs(xi):
        ninside += 1
print(ninside)
```

Comment: Thank you @xnx! Is there a way to count the dots on either side of the hyerbolic lines?

Comment: That's really a separate problem that should be asked in a new SO question, but I've added a quick edit to give you the idea.